# adding listener to invisible button in android

Tags: android, button

I am trying to add listener for a button.
with property visibility :invisible.
is it possible to add?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add listener.
But you cant click invisible button
so that listener cant be invoked at any time of Activity running...

but u can make transparent image as background and also text=""

so it wont visible to user also no need to make it as invisible.

Listener also invoked when user touch that place.

Comment: @Ganapathy:what do you mean by making transparent image as background ?My buttons are appearing grey ,i want to keep then on the image .so that they will be invisible .Can i do that ?

Comment: @Vamsi you can give background of button a transprent image or android:background="@android:color/transparent" so our button will be not be visible to user but click function will be active.

Comment: what do you mean by transparent image ? you mean the same image which is in the background @Ganapathy