# Android: To set a button invisible

Tags: android, button, dynamic, visibility

On double tap, buttons to be toggled visible/invisible. I created my layout dynamically. Its working if the btns are initially visible but I want them initially invisible.

My DoubleTap fn is

```
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (visible)
    {
        b1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        b2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        b3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        b4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        visible = false;
    }
    else
    {
        b1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        b2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        b3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        b4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        visible = true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

where "visible" is a boolean value.

I tried these in onCreate() and also in onStart()

```
    b1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    b4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    visible = false;
```

but if I add this its not getting visible on double tap. I checked them by Toast, its executed but not made visible.

Can anyone help. Both modification or fresh code is ok if it works.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Dude, [you cannot click an invisible Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216877/adding-listener-to-invisible-button-in-android). In your case a good solution to make a button disappear is to make it *transparent*.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Button btn=new Button(getBaseContext());
 btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

try this when you creating your button

Comment: Thank you for spending your valuable time to answer my question... I did the above but its not getting visible on double tap... Can you please try to help me in that...

Answer (score 0):

If you are in activity then

```
Button btn = new Button(YourActivity.this);
btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

And if you are in fragment then:

```
Button btn = new Button(getActivity());
btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

And if you are trying to make buttons invisible in onCreate method. Suppose you have done this in your onCreate:

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Then you have to do vice-versa of what you have done in on touch.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that the buttons cannot be clicked while being `View.INVISIBLE`. The right thing to do is to make them `transparent`.

[Have a look at this question and the related answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5216877/adding-listener-to-invisible-button-in-android)

Edit: [This question might help too!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8331326/android-how-do-you-make-a-button-invisible-but-still-active)